# How to find if a string exists only with numbers? (in LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query and I want to have addresses between a range of zipcodes from 1000 to 2000.

How do I find if the zipcode with a value `"3456 AB"` (I only check the 4 first characters) exists of only digits?

```cs
var address = address.Where(p => p.Zipcode != null
                              && p.Zipcode.Length > 4 
                              && p.Zipcode.Substring(0, 4).Isnumber() 
                              && Convert.ToInt32(p.Zipcode.Substring(0, 4)) > zipcodeFrom);
```

Comment: Is that in memory, on SQL Server or on some other database?

Comment: Can you give a simple example of expected input and output? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Does what you have not work? Or what is the question?

Comment: An exception as: "SECR" is not a number...

Answer (score 2):

You should just use TryParse, it returns bool if the string is convertable to an int.

Some dummy data to test on:

```
var addresses = new[]
{
    new { Zipcode = "3456 AB" }, // These of course have other fields,
    new { Zipcode = "345678"  }, // but in this example we only care
    new { Zipcode = "876543"  }, // about Zipcode
    new { Zipcode = "X3456"   },
    new { Zipcode = "5000 GG" },
};
```

The query:

```
    int zipcodeFrom = 4000;
    int parsedZipcode;

    var qualifiedAddresses = addresses
        .Where(p => true
            && p.Zipcode != null
            && p.Zipcode.Length >= 4
            && int.TryParse(p.Zipcode.Substring(0, 4), out parsedZipcode)
            && parsedZipcode > zipcodeFrom
        );
```

Output:

```
876543 
5000 GG
```

Comment: Why aren't you reusing `dummy`? You don't need to `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: Quite pretty the use of `true &&` :-) I like it. Note that I would use `uint` because otherwise *-999 ABCD* would be valid.

Comment: @xanatos - true that, I was doing twice the parsing. The variable is longer a "dummy", right? ;)

Comment: That's for conditions readability - now you can comment any of them because each has it's own line, they are aligned (even the first condition, because now the first condition is `true`, which doesn't change the result), plus when you comment all of them, it's still valid because of that `true`. If you want to align logical ORs, you use `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use Regex to check if the first four chars represent a number from 1000 to 2000. This would simplify your expression significantly:

```
var address = address.Where(p => p.Zipcode != null
    && Regex.Match(p.Zipcode, @"^[12]\d{3}").Success);
```

Comment: Regex is great and indispensible, but in such an easy case it's unnecessary to make the algorithm take the performance impact it implies.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
var valid = adress.Where(x => x.ZipCode != null)
    .Select(x => x.ZipCode)
    .Where(x => x.Take(4).All(Char.IsDigit));
```

The `Where`-clause checks the four first characters of every `ZipCode` to be all numbers. Be aware that when using `Take(4)` you will get an enumeration of type `char`, not just a string. Thus you can simply call [`x.IsDigit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7f0ddtxh(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if the character represents a number.

Comment: I think question asks about how to take zipcodes between 1000 and 2000, not take first 4 record

Answer (score 1):

You can match a 4 digits string and parse it.

```
var resultString = int.Parse(
    Regex.Match(zip, @"\d{4}").Value
    );
```

If you want the Linq equivalent

```
var linqEquiv = zip.Select((c, i) =>
  String.Join("",zip.Skip(i).Take(4))).FirstOrDefault(zip => 
    { int i; return int.TryParse(zip, out i) && i >= 1000 && i <= 2000 ; });
```

*Finally, with your class definition*

```
var linqEquivalent = address.Where(a => a.ZipCode.ToArray().Select((c, i) =>
    String.Join("", a.ZipCode.ToArray().Skip(i).Take(4))).FirstOrDefault(zip =>
        { int i; return int.TryParse(zip, out i) && i >= 1000 && i <= 2000; }) != null);
```

### test case

with the following list

```
var address = new List<Address>() {
    new Address() { ZipCode = "123 cap 1567 AB 6666" }, // 1567 matches conds
    new Address() { ZipCode = "123 cap 4567 AB 6666" },
    new Address() { ZipCode = "123 cap 4567 AB 1666" } }; // 1666 matches conds
```

`linqEquivalent` will contain the first and the third address.

Comment: LINQ does not support Regex.Match (& int.Parse too).

Comment: Added the Linq equivalent to my answer

Comment: I've revised my answer, assuming that `address` is a list of class with a `ZipCode` member...

Answer (score 1):

```
var valid = addresses
    .Where(a => 
        a.Zipcode != null 
        && a.Zipcode.Length > 4 
        && a.Zipcode.Substring(0, 4).All(char.IsDigit))
    .Select(a => new { Address = a, Zipcode = Convert.ToInt32(a.Zipcode.Substring(0, 4)) })
    .Where(a => a.Zipcode >= 1000 && a.Zipcode <= 2000)
    .Select(a => a.Address);
```

Keeping your original checks in - firstly we filter out all addresses where Zipcode is null, is less than 4 in length, or the first 4 characters are not all digits.

The we project a new sequence of an anonymous type containing the address and the 4 digit Zipcode as an int. We can then filter this collection by checking if the int Zipcode is within the range we require. Finally we return the original addresses.

Answer (score 0):

```
int intzipcode;

var address = address
    .Where(p => true
        && p.Zipcode != null
        && p.Zipcode.Length > 4
        && int.TryParse(p.Zipcode.Substring(0, 4), out intzipcode)
        && Convert.ToInt32(p.Zipcode.Substring(0, 4)) > 1000
        && Convert.ToInt32(p.Zipcode.Substring(0, 4)) < 2000
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers. I have tried it all.

Maybe it's LINQ-to-SQL. But all functions as All, char.IsDigit and Regex.Match doesn't work. The "table" from SQL Server was a view. So I changed the view for an extra field ZipcodeInt.

```
var address = address.Where(p => p.Zipcode != null
                                && p.Zipcode.Length > 4 
                                && p.ZipcodeInt > zipcodeFrom);
```